# If $f$ is entire, and $MRe(f(z))+NIm(f(z))$ is bounded, and M and N are real numbers, is $f$ constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

So I understand how bounding Re(f(z)) results in a constant f(z). The proof for that involved considering another function $e^{f(z)}$ and showing that the magnitude of that function contained only the bounded component, but I can't seem to figure out a function that would work analogously for this case. I'm having trouble getting a function of $f(z)$ that would isolate $MRe(f(z))+NIm(f(z))$. Should I abandon this strategy entirely?

Comment: Can you write $M\operatorname{Re} w + N \operatorname{Im} w$ as $\operatorname{Re} (\alpha\cdot w)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, $M Re(f) + N Im(f)$ is real valued if that's the question.

Comment: Can you find an $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $w\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $M \operatorname{Re} w + N \operatorname{Im} w = \operatorname{Re} (\alpha \cdot w)$?

Comment: I would think that such an $\alpha$ would have to depend on $w$, but I'm not sure. Is what you're getting at that if there is such an $\alpha$, I can use the bounded $Re(f(z))$ result to solve this one?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm getting at. And you should look at $\alpha\cdot w$ again. Decompose each factor in its real and imaginary parts, distribute, look.

Comment: oh wow! I think it's M-Ni. Thanks for the approach, I'll follow where this goes for a while... edit: oh wait the result falls out almost directly that was incredible, thank you